# To Activate RFCOMM in CSR8670 Audio Development Kit

Tags: bluetooth, android

I have a device CSR-8670 which act as SINK and on another side I have Android phone which act as Source. I am able to connect through RFCOMM when my both server and client is ANDROID phone but not able to connect when sink is CSR8670 Audio Development Kit and source is Android phone. Is there any way to enable or connect RFCOMM so that I can connect the kit with Android phone and can send data byte serially.

Comment: Can you provide HCI dump logs from your android device?

Comment: Hi are you still working on this project? I know it has been a long time but I have been able to do this (RFCOMM connection between android (data source) and 8670 (data sink) ) and am currently working on other projects related to 8670. If you are still interested in 8670 programming please let me know so we can share ideas.